# SQL: Avoid batch failing when processing

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server job that picks up a max of 1000 items each time in the queue for processing at an interval of 1 minutes.

In the job I use `MERGE INTO` to the table I need and mark the status of these items as complete and the job completes and will process the next batch in the next interval.

All good so far except recently there has been an incident where there is a problem in one of the item and since we are processing the batch in one single SQL statement, the whole batch has failed due to that one single item.

No big deal as we later identified the faulty one and have it patched and re-processed the whole failed batch.

What I am interested to know is what are some of the things I can do to avoid failing of the entire batch?

This time I know that the reason of this faulty item hence I can add a check to flush out this faulty item before the single `MERGE INTO` statement, but that does not cover other unknown errors.

Comment: A single statement is atomic - it either succeeds or fails as a whole. So technically, there is nothing you can do to prevent a single statement from failing without duplicating the logic that is implemented within the definition of that table. Often one chooses to do some level of "pre-screening" to handle the most common problems. Ultimately, you must decide where the logic to validate the correctness of your data resides and how much you wish to duplicate it. The more you duplicate, the more  you must test and the greater risk that a logic mismatch occurs.

Comment: You can't really stop it failing, but you can both do as SMor suggested and "pre-screen" (exclude or change things to avoid errors you know about) or you can go the option of notification (send some sort of message to someone who can look at it when it fails and get it fixed ASAP).

Comment: i am thinking of cursor but that will be overkill

Comment: People are normally against cursors because set-based operations are more efficient. But if you *NEED* 999/1000 things to go through, even if one fails, then perhaps a cursor is fine for your scenario. So if a cursor or similar alternative works for your needs, then use it.